Codewords of Subsystem Codes
I have a question about subsystem codes that came up when reading the article Universal transversal gates with color codes - a simplified approach. Subsystem codes are introduced in Section IV. A
The way they introduce it there is as follows: They only consider CSS-subsystem codes. The gauge group $\mathcal{G}$ is generated by $X$-type and $Z$-type generators. The stabiliser group $\mathcal{S}$ is the subgroup generated by all $X$-type and $Z$-type generators that commute with every element $g \in \mathcal{G}$.
As usual, the code space $C$ is the space of all states stabilised by all $s \in \mathcal{S}$, and by introducing the equivalence relation $\psi \sim \phi $ whenever there is $g \in \mathcal{G}\setminus \mathcal{S}$ with $g\psi = \phi $ we get a decomposition $C = A \otimes B$. I think I don't have a deep understanding yet of this decomposition which is probably the reason why I have the question I'll ask later.
Now, they make further assumptions, namely that the code space is one dimensional (so there is exactly one logical qubit) and that applying $X$ resp. $Z$ on all physical qubits implements the logical $\bar{X}$ resp. $\bar{Z}$.
Now they define in equation (23) and (24) codewords:
$$ |\bar{0} \rangle |g_X \rangle = \sum_{X(G) \in \mathcal{G}} X(G) | \mathbf{0} \rangle \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ (23)$$
$$ | \bar{1} \rangle | g_X \rangle = \bar{X} |\bar{0} \rangle |g_X \rangle \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ (24)$$
Here, these $X(G)$ are just the elements of $\mathcal{G}$ that are products of $X$ and identities, $| \mathbf{0} \rangle$ is the all-zero state on the physical qubits.
Later, in equation (25) and (26), they also define different candidates for codewords:
$$ |\bar{0} \rangle |g_Z \rangle = \sum_{X(S) \in \mathcal{S}} X(S) | \mathbf{0} \rangle \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ (25)$$
$$ | \bar{1} \rangle | g_Z \rangle = \bar{X} |\bar{0} \rangle |g_Z \rangle \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\ (26)$$
I do understand that these are code words. What is boggling my mind though is that the notation $|\bar{0} \rangle |g_X \rangle$ suggests that all of these states are product states. Is it true that these states are product states with respect to the decomposition $C = A \otimes B$ into logical qubits and gauge qubits that I mentioned before? And if so, how can one see that this is the case?
